# Execution log not working in Suitescript 2.0 Client script

Tags: netsuite

I have a suitelet and i have attached client script to suitelet this way

form.clientScriptModulePath = '../Client/cancel.js';

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope public
 */

define(['N/log'], function(myLog) {

 return({

 fieldChanged: function(context){       

         myLog.debug({
         title: 'hello!',
         details: 'world'
         });

        alert(context.line);                    
 }     
 });             
});
```

This is a test script, here alert is giving me the line number but log in not working. Ideally it should log to the parent suitelet. What is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form-level Client Scripts, which is what you've made by attaching your Client Script to the Suitelet Form, do not have an Execution Log as there is no associated Script or Script Deployment record.

I recommend using the browser console and `console.log` to print debugging messages from your Suitelet, then removing them once the script is ready.